# C++ Builder 10 - Compiling any project gives error?

Tags: delphi, ide, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I just installed C++ Builder 10 (Seattle) trial but now facing a strange error when trying to compile any (new or existing) VCL Forms application.

[image]

It's a clean installation, no settings were modified etc. I'm using Windows 10. How to solve this?

Comment: Ask the vendor for support

Comment: Now reinstalling to see if it helps...

Comment: Are you perhaps building a 64bit application? There have been some reports of 64bit compiler to not working properly (generating different compilation results every time even if code has not been changed)  in Delphi 10 Seattle. I assume there is a possibility that 64bit C++ compiler might also be affected by this.

Comment: Reinstalled. Not working both on 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Cannot submit report. QC returns databases errors upon submiting. Just great! Everything in chaos at Embarcadero.

Comment: QC is not used. You should use QP, the new system: http://quality.embarcadero.com/ (note my answer below includes a link to this bug, which is already in the system. Vote for it instead of adding a new one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug [RSP 11768](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11768), which I suspect will be fixed in Update 1. See also [this forum thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=709589&tstart=0).

There are a number of solutions in that bug report:

- Add borlndmm.dll to the delay-loaded list; the method in question is never called, so the fact it isn't found doesn't cause a runtime error
- Using impdef, create a new import library for the memory manager (borlndmm.dll / memmgr.def, and remove two exports (`__dbk_fcall_wrapper` and `dbkFCallWrapperAddr`; see the bug for details)
- Replace memmgr.lib with the version from XE8

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

1. Go to Project/Options...
2. Click on "C++ Compiler" and find "Use 'classic' Borland Compiler"
3. Disable it

In existing projects built in previous versions of C++ Builder this may cause the following linker errors:

> Unresolved external '___seh_personality_v0'   Unresolved external
>   '__Unwind_SjLj_Register'   Unresolved external '___cxa_begin_catch'
>   Unresolved external '___cxa_rethrow'   Unresolved external
>   '___cxa_end_catch'   Unresolved external '__Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
>   Unresolved external '__Unwind_Resume'    Unresolved external
>   '___cpp_terminate'

To remove those errors go to

1. Project/Options...
2. C++ (Shared Options) / Library Path
3. Remove '`$(BDS)\lib\win32\release\`'

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed an **older** version of RAD Studio **after a newer version was already installed**. In my case I installed XE2 after XE10 was already installed.

In my Windows PATH the directories of the newer version (XE10)

e.g.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin`

were listed **after** the directories of the older version (XE2)

e.g.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin`

therefore an old version of borlndmm.dll was found instead of the actual one.

So I just moved the newer PATH records in front of the newer ones, restarted RAD Studio and everything was fine. I mean,... as it was before.